# OpenVPN: how can I assign specific netmask for clients from server side?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have an [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/) server running on **Ubuntu Linux v14**.
This is an example of the **ifconfig** for a connecting client:

```
luis@Zarzamoro:/etc/openvpn$ sudo ifconfig tun0
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:192.168.211.141  P-t-P:192.168.211.142  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I want the **network mask** of any connecting client to `255.255.255.0`, instead of `255.255.255.255`.

Of course, I can change it from *client-side* in multiple ways, for example:

```
# ifconfig tun0 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

... some script at `/etc/network/if-up.d/`...etc.

But I would like to do it **from the server**, if this is possible.
This is: **any connecting client** would receive (from the OpenVPN server) something like:

```
luis@Zarzamoro:/etc/openvpn$ sudo ifconfig tun0
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:192.168.211.141  P-t-P:192.168.211.142  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Can this be done?

Answers that will work for both **Windows and Linux clients** are preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `topology` **parameter** at `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` (or wherever it is) :

```
# Network topology:
topology subnet
```

and specify the IP address pool (that includes the **network mask**) at the same file (the comments only show example numbers, so replace by yours):

```
# Configure server mode and supply a VPN subnet
# for OpenVPN to draw client addresses from.
# The server will take 10.8.0.1 for itself,
# the rest will be made available to clients.
# Each client will be able to reach the server
# on 10.8.0.1. Comment this line out if you are
# ethernet bridging. See the man page for more info.
#server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
server 192.168.211.0 255.255.255.0
```

Restart the server, by the way:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn restart
```

That should be all.

Additional points:

- According to the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/openvpn) the default topology mode is `net30`, so the need to change it.
- According to the same man page, the **topology subnet** mode `works only on OpenVPN v2.1 or higher`.